# How to further process a 2 dimensional list created with tuples

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, permutation

I created with

`Tuples[{{USD, EUR, JPY}, {UP, DOWN}}]`

the following result:

`{{USD, UP}, {USD, DOWN}, {EUR, UP}, {EUR, DOWN}, {JPY, UP}, {JPY, DOWN}}`

I want to further have a 3 dimensional list of all combinations - but the same currency does not appear twice. Example output

`{{{USD, UP}, {EUR, UP}, {JPY, UP}},
{{USD, UP}, {EUR, UP}, {JPY, DOWN}},
{{USD, UP}, {EUR, DOWN}, {JPY, UP}}, 
{{USD, UP}, {EUR, DOWN}, {JPY, DOWN}},
...
{{USD, DOWN}, {EUR, DOWN}, {JPY, DOWN}}}`

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
Tuples@Outer[List, {USD, EUR, JPY}, {UP, DOWN}]
(*
  {{{USD, UP}, {EUR, UP}, {JPY, UP}},
   {{USD, UP}, {EUR, UP}, {JPY, DOWN}},
   {{USD, UP}, {EUR, DOWN}, {JPY, UP}},
   {{USD, UP}, {EUR, DOWN}, {JPY, DOWN}},
   {{USD, DOWN}, {EUR, UP}, {JPY, UP}},
   {{USD, DOWN}, {EUR, UP}, {JPY, DOWN}},
   {{USD, DOWN}, {EUR, DOWN}, {JPY, UP}},
   {{USD, DOWN}, {EUR, DOWN}, {JPY, DOWN}}}
*)
```

Comment: I can't beat that.  I tried. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one way is to use `Tuples` again after some judicious partitioning:

```
Tuples[Partition[Tuples[{{"USD", "EUR", "JPY"}, {"UP", "DOWN"}}], 2]]
```

Note the `2` is the length of the second set in the original `Tuples` so you could write your own function:

```
myTuples[list1_List, list2_List] := Tuples[Partition[Tuples[{list1, list2}], Length[list2]]]
```